# Chai assertion, unable to identify property using should / expect

Tags: mocha.js, chai, should.js

Hello: Need your help on a `chai` assertion.

I have a JSON response as shown below. I want to assert that it contains "Lastname is mandatory" only.

I tried using this statement but the error i get is `AssertionError: expected [ Array(2) ] to have a deep property '#text'`. Please help how to write this correctly.

**using expect**

```
chai.expect(data.response.error).to.have.deep.property('#text', 'Lastname is mandatory.');
```

**using should**

```
data.response.error.should.have.deep.property('#text', 'Lastname is mandatory.');
```

**Response JSON**

```
{
    response: {
        error: [
            {
            '@id': '1000',
            '#text': 'Firstname is mandatory.'
            },
            {
            '@id': '10001',
            '#text': 'Lastname is mandatory.'
            }
        ],
        result: 
        {
            status: '0'
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

#### Prior to Chai version 4

The use of `deep` with [`property`](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property) requires that you pass a complete path to the property you want to test. In other words, `deep.property` won't do a search through all the properties for you. As the [documentation](http://chaijs.com/api/bdd/#method_property) puts it:

> If the `deep` flag is set, you can use dot- and bracket-notation for deep references into objects and arrays.

Something like:

```
data.response.should.have.deep.property("error[0].#text");
```

Or you can start the path to the property with an array index if the object on which you use `should` is an array:

```
data.response.error.should.have.deep.property("[0].#text");
```

Here is a complete example derived from the code you show:

```
const chai = require("chai");
chai.should();

const data = {
    response: {
        error: [
            {
            '@id': '1000',
            '#text': 'Firstname is mandatory.'
            },
            {
            '@id': '10001',
            '#text': 'Lastname is mandatory.'
            }
        ],
        result:
        {
            status: '0'
        }
    }
};

it("works", () => {
    data.response.should.have.deep.property("error[0].#text");
    // Or this, which looks weird but is allowed...
    data.response.error.should.have.deep.property("[0].#text");
});
```

#### Chai version 4 and later

The OP was using a release of Chai earlier than version 4. If you are using Chai version 4 and over, the flag to use to is not `.deep` anymore but `.nested`. So in earlier versions where you would use `data.response.should.have.deep.property("error[0].#text");` in version 4 or later you'd use `data.response.should.have.nested.property("error[0].#text");`

Comment: Thanks much for the details.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer from @shvaikalesh at [github](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/965). It has the relevant answer to my question which i provide [here](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/965) for future reference + the code extract is also below for quick reference.

```
chai.expect(data.response.error.some(e => e['#text'] == 'Lastname is mandatory.')).to.be.true
```